# Error while importing tensorflow. "Please exit the tensorflow source tree"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow, but when I run my server I get the following error:

```
Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/my-link/')
def my_link():
  import tensorflow as tf
  cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
  model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
      include_top=True,
      weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,)

  loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
  model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
  model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host="localhost", port=3000, debug=True)
```

I'm not sure how I can fix this problem. Can someone please provide an answer along with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my python interpreter to 3.10.8.